# Java: Add 2 animated objects (paintComponent) on the same JPanel

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics, jpanel

I have a class that creates an animated object (an wormlike animation) by repainting it through a timer. 
And another class that have my Frame and a Panel.
When I create 2 (mov and mov2) instances of this object and add it to the panel, they appear in separeted panels (or seems like). Heres the code.

```
public class Movimento extends JComponent{
    int t;  
    int a;  
    int[][] matriz;

    public Movimento(int tamanho, int area){        
        t = tamanho;
        a = area;

        gerarMatriz();
        gerarPanel();

        ActionListener counter = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
                movimentarMatriz();
                repaint();
            }
        };          
        new Timer(1, counter).start();
    }

    public void gerarPanel(){
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(a, a));
    }   

    public void gerarMatriz(){
       /*
        *Generates an array[][] with initial coordinates
        */
    }

    public void movimentarMatriz(){
       /*
        * add a new coordinate to the last space of the array  
        */
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for(int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++){
            g.drawRect(matriz[i][0],matriz[i][1],1,1);
        }
    }
```

Then I create the new Movimento objects here

```
public class GeraImg{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Gera Imagem");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    Movimento mov = new Movimento(1000,400);
    Movimento mov2 = new Movimento(100,400);

    public GeraImg(){
        fazerFrame();   
    }

    public void fazerFrame(){

        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBackground(new Color(150,200,20,255));
        panel.add(mov2);
        panel.add(mov);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new GeraImg();      
    }
}
```

then I get 2 separeted animated panels side by side, not 2 worms inside the same panel.

Is the concept totally wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
panel.add(mov2);
panel.add(mov);
```

By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout, so yes your two components area added side by side.

You can try using:

```
panel.setLayout(null);
panel.add(mov2);
panel.add(mov);
```

This will allow the components to be randomly positioned within the panel. But now you are responsible for using setSize(...) and setLocation(...) on your component so the component can be painted properly in the panel.

However, a better approach is to create your own class that implements its own painting method. Something like:

```
public class Movimento()
{
    ...

    public void paintMe(Graphics g)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++)
        {
            g.drawRect(matriz[i][0],matriz[i][1],1,1);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would create your component to paint all of your Movimento objects. Something like:

```
public class MovimentoAnimator extends JPanel
{
    private List<Movimento> movimentos = new ArrayList<Movimento>();

    public void addMovimento(Movimento movimento)
    {
        movimentos.add( movimento );
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (Movimento movimento: movimentos
        {
            movimento.paintMe( g );
        }
    }
}
```

This class would also be responsible for the animation.

Comment: It worked like a charm. I set the layout to null and set the location and size of each component, they are animated in the same space.
I'll be looking into creating a separeted class for animating those components. Thank you!!